# Error on localhost after start SonarQube on windows

Tags: ruby, sonarqube

So after I downloaded and ran SonarQube on windows 8.1 and also on windows 10 I get this error when I try to look this address: localhost:9000

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: C:/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/i18n-0.4.2/lib/i18n.rb:1: Invalid char `\34' ('') in expression
ěě î ě  ě ě !íîëîîěěëîîěëíěîďďěîďďëďîđ�
ěďîěďďîěďďďëďďďďďëďďďďďďH
```

There is not any error on console, the last line is:

```
jvm 1    | 2015.12.13 12:42:02 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

I didn't find anything on the internet. It is maybe a Ruby error...
Now I have a fresh windows install with 64bit java (i tried with 32bit too... and it was the same)

Does anybody know what is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you try looking at _<sonarqube-install-dir>\logs\sonar.log_ file and see if you find something interesting there? If that doesn't help, go to _<sonarqube-install-dir>\conf\sonar.properties_ file, look for **sonar.log.level** in the file and uncomment the line and change its value to **TRACE** (sonar.log.level=TRACE). Restart sonarqube server and check sonar.log file again... Btw, which version of SQ did you download?

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but is it possible that files have been unzipped with incorrect encoding ?

Comment: I installed the latest version, so 5.2.
There was not any intresting in the logs, I will change the debug level in the afternnon.